# Weka time series auto complete missing dates

Tags: time-series, weka, forecasting

I am using Weka's time series package for a forecasting task. I need to implement the forecast programmatically in java.

I followed the example given in 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka#TimeSeriesAnalysisandForecastingwithWeka-2Requirements. However, in some situation, if the time series (weekly data) is not consecutive

```
e.g. 
2010-03-05
2010-03-26
```

The results from code will differ from what weka ui give. The reason is, I can see from weka's UI output that weka automatically supplements missing dates as follows:

```
2010-03-05
2010-03-12
2010-03-19
2010-03-26
```

with predicted values as train values.

Anyone know how to make this happen in java code?